I want to detect in the client-side script that I have gotten a 401 error when fetching data with bad PAT (Using Azure DevOps REST API)
When I use an expired PAT attempting to access the REST end-point, in the browser's Dev Tools console window I will get:
GET https://dev.azure.com/contoso/_apis/connectionData net::ERR_FAILED 401 (Unauthorized)

But it is impossible to get the fact that there's a 401 status code from inside JavaScript.  I've tried fetch with "then" / "catch" / and await with try/catch.  I've also tried XMLHttpRequest.  The only error I get is:
TypeError: Failed to fetch

Since the browser is clearly seeing the 401 (Unauthorized), I'd like to be detect that status code.
The browser Dev Tools console also has the following:
Access to fetch at 'https://dev.azure.com/contoso/_apis/connectionData' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.


The Network tab shows the 401 status as well:

Using no-cors hides makes everything opaque, and you don't get the 401 status.
Here's a runnable sample:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
(async function () {
  "use strict";

  const API_ORGANIZATION="contoso"

  const expiredPat = 'ts44tplifj4hbbzeitcz5dg5az4q3mpqcxqmrxo4zwlgy3scobzq'
  const pat = expiredPat

  // Fetch data from Azure DevOps
  async function ado(api) {
    const url = `https://dev.azure.com/${API_ORGANIZATION}/_apis/${api}`
    console.log(`url: ${url}`)
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(':' + pat),
        Accept: 'application/json',
      }
    })
    return await response.json()
  }

  // get the connectionData from Azure DevOps
  async function getConnectionData() {
    return await ado('connectionData')
  }

  function topText(text) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = text
    document.body.prepend(p)
    return p
  }

  // show the connection Data at the top of the window
  async function showConnectionData() {
    try {
      const result = await getConnectionData();
      topText(`Azure DevOps access authenticated as: ${result.authenticatedUser.providerDisplayName}`)
    } catch(err) {
      const p = topText(`${err} - See console`)
      p.style.color = "red";
      p.style.fontWeight = "999"
    }
  }

  async function tryFetch() {
    try {
      await showConnectionData()
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    tryFetch()
  });

})();


    </script>
  </body>
</html>




is https://dev.azure.com/contoso/_apis something you have control over? If so, add CORS handling to it. If not, make the request through the server that serves your web page that calls this API

@JaromandaX neither of these are satisfactory answers.   I'm not looking for an alternative solution.  I am seeking to understand how I can capture the fact that there's a 401 status, which is clearly visible in Chrome's DevTools, in both the Console window and the Network tab, but I am unable to get the status code from JavaScript.   The only acceptable answer will be 1) how I can do this from JavaScript on the client side given the scenario I outlined, or 2) an explanation, (with evidence!) as to why this is not possible.

a) I have given no answers, b) you haven't addressed my questions. c) you can't access cross origin response without CORS headers being present - 1) you can't if there's a CORS issue, 2) learn about CORS

I'm trying to learn about CORS, hence the question to my peers.   Looks like someone who understands what's going on actually gave me an answer.  You should check it out.

I think you'll agree my last comment supplies the same information. I didn't post an answer because I asked if it were possible for you to add CORS headers to the server, since that is one solution, and if you couldn't, the other solution is to proxy the request through your own server - therefore in either case, you would then have access to the response status, which is what your question asks - i.e. you want to "detect 401 status" - so thank you for trying to make it look like I don't know what I'm talking about, but, in fact, I do know exactly 2 ways to answer your question.

The issue is caused by the CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing).
According to this official document about Azure DevOps REST API:

Azure DevOps Services supports CORS, which enables JavaScript code served from a domain other than dev.azure.com/* to make Ajax requests to Azure DevOps Services REST APIs. Each request must provide credentials (PATs and OAuth access tokens are both supported options).

This means that Azure DevOps Services supports CORS when you provided the correct credentials. When the PAT is incorrect, the server responds with a 401 Unauthorized status and since the credentials are invalid, the server does not proceed with the request and does not include CORS headers.
For example, I tested the issue with the following script (replace the orgname and pat with the actual value):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Azure DevOps CORS Example</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Azure DevOps API Response</h1>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <div id="response"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/connectionData',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("" + ":" + "pat")
                }
            }).done(function(results) {
                $('#status').text('Status: 200 OK');
                $('#response').text(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#status').text('Status: ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + textStatus);
                $('#response').text('Response: ' + errorThrown);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

When run the script with a correct PAT, you can see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* in the response headers.

When run the script with an expired PAT, there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* in the response headers.

To workaround the CORS issue, you can refer this question for more details.
In my test, I tried to use the CORS Anywhere, a public demo of the CORS Anywhere service. It allows you to bypass the CORS restrictions when making requests to different domains. This should only be used for development purposes.
Steps:

Visit https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/corsdemo and click the "Request temporary access to the demo server" button. You will have temporary access to the demo server.
Add the https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com to the URL in the script, which becomes to https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://dev.azure.com/orgname/_apis/connectionData
Now we can find the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response headers and get the 401 status code.

Test result:


I think what you are saying is that it is not possible to get the 401 Unauthorized in JavaScript, even though the 401 Unauthorized shows up the Chrome DevTools console window and Network tab.    Correct?
And the reason is because since the PAT is invalid, CORS blocks the request and won't even return the actual status code.
Is that what you're saying?

Yes, when the server responds with a 401 Unauthorized status due to invalid credentials, it does not include CORS headers.  The DevTools console and Network tab can show all network activity, including responses that are blocked by CORS policies. This allows you to see the status code and other details for debugging purposes. At the same time, the browser will block the response and not expose any details to the JavaScript code.
